# Is there a problem with Thunderbolt to HDMI in Lion?

Tags: macos, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

After upgrading to Lion on my recently purchased Macbook Pro 13" base model I'm having trouble connecting to an HDLCD TV.  My TV is connected to a receiver.  Sometimes when I connect I get 5.1 sound to play through my speakers.  Sometimes it's 2.1 sound. And other times no sound can be played.  Even just getting the laptop to display to the TV is hit or miss.

Is this a known issue?  Any suggestions on how to get things to work consistently?

UPDATE:  It appears that connecting the laptop to the TV is not problematic if there is nothing playing at the time the connection is made.  I get anomalous results if I make a connection while playing something.

Comment: I've seen several questions like this - there may be something that needs a patch. Have you filed a bug or reported it to Apple support?

Answer (score 1):

The best chance of success (and Lion doesn't seem to affect this either way) is to have the cord connected when the TV is turned on. This lets the mac and the TV negotiate the formats that the TV supports. Sometimes hot plugging it, even though it's supposed to work causes interference (snow) or worse on the TV until you make the connection again.